# Spark metrics on wordcount example

Tags: apache-spark, metrics

I read the section Metrics on [spark website](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.1/monitoring.html). I wish to try it on the wordcount example, I can't make it work.

spark/conf/metrics.properties :

```
# Enable CsvSink for all instances
*.sink.csv.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.sink.CsvSink

# Polling period for CsvSink
*.sink.csv.period=1

*.sink.csv.unit=seconds

# Polling directory for CsvSink
*.sink.csv.directory=/home/spark/Documents/test/

# Worker instance overlap polling period
worker.sink.csv.period=1

worker.sink.csv.unit=seconds

# Enable jvm source for instance master, worker, driver and executor
master.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource

worker.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource

driver.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource

executor.source.jvm.class=org.apache.spark.metrics.source.JvmSource
```

I run my app in local like in the documentation :

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit   --class "SimpleApp"   --master local[4]   target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar
```

I checked /home/spark/Documents/test/ and it is empty.

What did I miss?

---

Shell:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit   --class "SimpleApp"   --master local[4]  --conf   spark.metrics.conf=/home/spark/development/spark/conf/metrics.properties  target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar
Spark assembly has been built with Hive, including Datanucleus jars on classpath
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.3.0
WARN Utils: Your hostname, cv-local resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 192.168.1.64 instead (on interface eth0)
WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: spark
INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: spark
INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(spark); users with modify permissions: Set(spark)
INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@cv-local.local:35895]
INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 35895.
INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/spark-447d56c9-cfe5-4f9d-9e0a-6bb476ddede6/blockmgr-4eaa04f4-b4b2-4b05-ba0e-fd1aeb92b289
INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 265.4 MB
INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /tmp/spark-fae11cd2-937e-4be3-a273-be8b4c4847df/httpd-ca163445-6fff-45e4-9c69-35edcea83b68
INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 52828.
INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://cv-local.local:4040
INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/spark/workspace/IdeaProjects/wordcount/target/scala-2.10/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar at http://192.168.1.64:52828/jars/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar with timestamp 1444049152348
INFO Executor: Starting executor ID <driver> on host localhost
INFO AkkaUtils: Connecting to HeartbeatReceiver: akka.tcp://sparkDriver@cv-local.local:35895/user/HeartbeatReceiver
INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 60320
INFO BlockManagerMaster: Trying to register BlockManager
INFO BlockManagerMasterActor: Registering block manager localhost:60320 with 265.4 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(<driver>, localhost, 60320)
INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager
INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(34046) called with curMem=0, maxMem=278302556
INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 33.2 KB, free 265.4 MB)
INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(5221) called with curMem=34046, maxMem=278302556
INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 5.1 KB, free 265.4 MB)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on localhost:60320 (size: 5.1 KB, free: 265.4 MB)
INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_0_piece0
INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from textFile at SimpleApp.scala:11
WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
WARN LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
INFO FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
INFO SparkContext: Starting job: count at SimpleApp.scala:12
INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (count at SimpleApp.scala:12) with 2 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 0(count at SimpleApp.scala:12)
INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at filter at SimpleApp.scala:12), which has no missing parents
INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2848) called with curMem=39267, maxMem=278302556
INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.8 KB, free 265.4 MB)
INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2056) called with curMem=42115, maxMem=278302556
INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.0 KB, free 265.4 MB)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on localhost:60320 (size: 2.0 KB, free: 265.4 MB)
INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_1_piece0
INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:839
INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from Stage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[2] at filter at SimpleApp.scala:12)
INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1391 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1391 bytes)
INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
INFO Executor: Fetching http://192.168.1.64:52828/jars/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar with timestamp 1444049152348
INFO Utils: Fetching http://192.168.1.64:52828/jars/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar to /tmp/spark-cab5a940-e2a4-4caf-8549-71e1518271f1/userFiles-c73172c2-7af6-4861-a945-b183edbbafa1/fetchFileTemp4229868141058449157.tmp
INFO Executor: Adding file:/tmp/spark-cab5a940-e2a4-4caf-8549-71e1518271f1/userFiles-c73172c2-7af6-4861-a945-b183edbbafa1/simple-project_2.10-1.0.jar to class loader
INFO CacheManager: Partition rdd_1_1 not found, computing it
INFO CacheManager: Partition rdd_1_0 not found, computing it
INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/spark/development/spark/conf/metrics.properties:2659+2659
INFO HadoopRDD: Input split: file:/home/spark/development/spark/conf/metrics.properties:0+2659
INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(7840) called with curMem=44171, maxMem=278302556
INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_1_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 7.7 KB, free 265.4 MB)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_0 in memory on localhost:60320 (size: 7.7 KB, free: 265.4 MB)
INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block rdd_1_0
INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(8648) called with curMem=52011, maxMem=278302556
INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_1_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 8.4 KB, free 265.4 MB)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added rdd_1_1 in memory on localhost:60320 (size: 8.4 KB, free: 265.4 MB)
INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block rdd_1_1
INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1). 2399 bytes result sent to driver
INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0). 2399 bytes result sent to driver
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) in 139 ms on localhost (1/2)
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) in 133 ms on localhost (2/2)
INFO DAGScheduler: Stage 0 (count at SimpleApp.scala:12) finished in 0.151 s
INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
INFO DAGScheduler: Job 0 finished: count at SimpleApp.scala:12, took 0.225939 s
INFO SparkContext: Starting job: count at SimpleApp.scala:13
INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 1 (count at SimpleApp.scala:13) with 2 output partitions (allowLocal=false)
INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: Stage 1(count at SimpleApp.scala:13)
INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at filter at SimpleApp.scala:13), which has no missing parents
INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2848) called with curMem=60659, maxMem=278302556
INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.8 KB, free 265.3 MB)
INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2056) called with curMem=63507, maxMem=278302556
INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_2_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 2.0 KB, free 265.3 MB)
INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_2_piece0 in memory on localhost:60320 (size: 2.0 KB, free: 265.4 MB)
INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_2_piece0
INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 2 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:839
INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from Stage 1 (MapPartitionsRDD[3] at filter at SimpleApp.scala:13)
INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 2 tasks
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1391 bytes)
INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3, localhost, PROCESS_LOCAL, 1391 bytes)
INFO Executor: Running task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2)
INFO Executor: Running task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3)
INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_1_0 locally
INFO Executor: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2). 1830 bytes result sent to driver
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 2) in 9 ms on localhost (1/2)
INFO BlockManager: Found block rdd_1_1 locally
INFO Executor: Finished task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3). 1830 bytes result sent to driver
INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 1.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 3) in 10 ms on localhost (2/2)
INFO DAGScheduler: Stage 1 (count at SimpleApp.scala:13) finished in 0.011 s
INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: count at SimpleApp.scala:13, took 0.024084 s
Lines with a: 5, Lines with b: 12
```

Comment: did it produce any error log?

Comment: I just edit my post to add the log that appear on the shell when I run my application and there isn't any error. Is there another log file that I should look at? I don't know where I can see if the file metrics.properties is "loaded" when I run the application.

Comment: in your spark code, you did specify where to write the results? I presume this is at  /home/spark/Documents/test/ ? You should be able to see if metrices.properties is included in your package when you assemble your jar

Comment: No I didn't specify anything like that in my code. I just copy/paste the simpleApp example of spark. I assumed that spark will write a csv file with some metrics by default. What should I add?

Comment: Sorry, I just forgot to sbin/stop-all and sbin/start-all..Now I have some files in my directory, but there is still something that I don't understand. I look in the file worker.memUsed_MB.csv and the column value is aways 0. Have you any idea why?

Comment: based on your code, you are running locally on 4 cores, maybe it is just because your dataset is small that it got rounded to 0, if you increase your data size, maybe you will be more memory used by the worker nodes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91397/discussion-between-germaingum-and-gameofthrows).

Comment: Have you tried to enable the ConsoleSink first?

Answer (score 5):

I made it work specifying in the spark submit the path to the metrics file

```
--files=/yourPath/metrics.properties --conf spark.metrics.conf=./metrics.properties
```